# What is the best major mode to use in Emacs for Laravel + Vuejs

Tags: laravel, emacs, vue.js

Hello I am now practicing to use emacs as my primary editor in developing Laravel app. Together with Vue.js. When I research online I found out that some are using "web-mode". Are there any alternative to this? I didn't face any issue though, for now. But if I find some issue its good if I have something to replace it with.

I have also try using this https://github.com/AdamNiederer/vue-mode. But this one is not good in auto formatting of the codes.

Comment: It's been 3 months have you by any chance had any progress? I'm trying to run vue-mode with prettier for auto formatting on save it seems to be working alright I'm just missing autocomplete / snippets